# regex for ipv4 classfull address?

Tags: javascript, ip

find class of given ip address ie. 192.168.0.0 belongs to class A.

Comment: Think twice before ask.

Answer (score 2):

check the first octate of ipv4 using following regex

**regex for class A address**
(^(((([1-9]?[0-9]))|1[0-1][0-9]|12[0-7]))$)

**regex for class b address**
1((2[8-9])|([3-8][0-9])|9[0-1])

**regex for class c address**
(19[2-9])|(2(([0-1][0-9])|(2[0-3])))